# Django can't import ckeditor in settings but can in shell?

Tags: javascript, python, django, import, ckeditor

CKeditor for some reason can not be found when loading from settings, but importing from python shell it works fine.

Django 1.7. Python(2.7.9) is an alternate install. Installed ckeditor via `pip2.7 install django-ckeditor`

https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor

**Without** **ckeditor** in settings.py:

```
[user@server mysite]$ python2.7 manage.py shell
Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb  1 2015, 21:31:28) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import ckeditor
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
[user@server mysite]$ python2.7 manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /var/www/mysite/static

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes

0 static files copied to '/var/www/mysite/static', 2357 unmodified.
```

**Added 'ckeditor'** to settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'ckeditor ',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'allauth',
    'documentation',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'app',
    'thunderdome',
    'suit',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
   # 'supplementtut',
    'dbmail',
    'tinymce', 
)

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
```

Shell, collectstatic, runserver all the same:

```
[user@server mysite]$ python2.7 manage.py collectstatic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named ckeditor 
[user@server mysite]$
```

Verified it's installed:

```
[user@server mysite]$ cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ckeditor
[user@server ckeditor]$ ls -l
total 92
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users 1371 Apr  6 13:03 fields.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users 1975 Apr  6 13:03 fields.pyc
drwxr-xr-x 2 user domain users 4096 Apr  6 13:03 image
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users  297 Apr  6 13:03 image_processing.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users  611 Apr  6 13:03 image_processing.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users  721 Apr  6 13:03 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users  853 Apr  6 13:03 __init__.pyc
drwxr-xr-x 3 user domain users 4096 Apr  6 13:03 management
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users    0 Apr  6 13:03 models.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users  144 Apr  6 13:03 models.pyc
drwxr-xr-x 3 user domain users 4096 Apr  6 13:03 static
drwxr-xr-x 3 user domain users 4096 Apr  6 13:03 templates
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users  411 Apr  6 13:03 urls.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users  649 Apr  6 13:03 urls.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users 1025 Apr  6 13:03 utils.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users 2207 Apr  6 13:03 utils.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users 4749 Apr  6 13:03 views.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users 5089 Apr  6 13:03 views.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users 4583 Apr  6 13:03 widgets.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 user domain users 4957 Apr  6 13:03 widgets.pyc
[user@server ckeditor]$
```

**Update:** 
Checked to verify it was installed:

Pip Freeze:

```
[user@server mysite]$ pip2.7 freeze | grep ckeditor
django-ckeditor==4.4.7
```

Comment: You could use: `pip freeze | grep ckeditor` to verify that django-ckeditor is actually installed. Additionally, check that the `CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH` variable is set in `settings.py`.

Comment: Added what you suggested with same results.

Comment: Gee, It appears all it's fine. And I suggest you to use a virtual environment to isolate your projects; Because of you are using python 2.7.9, you should use virtualenv (you know `pip2.7 install virtualenv`), then create a virtual environment using: `virtualenv my_virtual_env`, then activate the virtual environment: `source my_virtual_env/bin/activate`, then install the modules you are gonna to use in your project, i.e. `pip install django==1.7 django-ckeditor`. And finally create your project with `django-admin.py startproject project_name`.

Comment: Thats a lot more of a deal then you would believe, the way that this server is setup is not something I can put into a virtual environment and run quickly.

Comment: Caramba!, that is what happen when the other side don't know the whole history. :)

Answer (score 4):

You have a trailing space in your `INSTALLED_APPS`: Try `'ckeditor'` instead of `'ckeditor '`.